# Serializer is returning "Model object" instead of specific field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem. I'm creating an API with Django REST framework and I created serializer to return recipes and ingredients to cook it.

models.py:

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))

class Tag(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=False, verbose_name=('name'))

class ListTag(models.Model):
        recipes = models.ForeignKey(Recipes, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipes')
        tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tag')
```

I have the classes `Recipes`, `Tag` (ingredients) and `ListTag` is the list that contains each ingredient with the id of the receipt.

serializers.py

```
class RecipesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredient = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, source='recipes')
    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = ('title', 'ingredient')

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag

class ListTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
     )
    class Meta:
        model = ListeTag
        fields = ('recipes','tag')
```

Results

For `RecipesSerializer`

```
{
    "title": "Pancakes à la canadienne",
    "ingredient": [
        "ListTag object",
        "ListTag object",
        "ListTag object"
    ]
}
```

But I want

```
{
    "title": "Pancakes à la canadienne",
    "ingredient": [
         {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "milk"
         },
         {
             "id": 3,
             "name": "rice"
         },
         {
             "id": 4,
             "name": "salade"
         },
         {
             "id": 5,
             "name": "tomato"
         }
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "title": "Pancakes à la canadienne",
    "ingredient": ["milk","rice","salade","tomato"]
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, your `ListTag` model is a brute force way of creating a many-to-many relationship in Django. You could use a `ManyToMany` field between `Recipes` and `Tag` instead to get similar results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Nested relationships like:

```
class RecipesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recipes = ListTagSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipes
        fields = ('title', 'recipes')

class ListTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='tag.id')
    tag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ListeTag
        fields = ('id','tag')
```

Learn more about Nested relationships [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)